# Building qtwebengine of Qt 5.12.4 on msvc2017 to enable proprietary codecs

Tags: qt, qt5, codec, toolchain, qtwebengine

I want to build Qt 5.12.4 on Windows 10 to have qtwebengine with proprietary codec for x86 applications but I get the `64-bit cross-building or native toolchain is required` error as follows by running `qmake .\qtwebengine -- -webengine-proprietary-codecs` command.

[image: qmake webengine with proprietary codecs]
Before running *qmake* command, I do the following steps:

1. Run Windows command prompt as Administrator. change directory to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build`

and run the following script:

> vcvarsall.bat amd64_x86

I run this command because ***I want to build Qt WebEngine for x86 applications.***

2. Change directory to

`D:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\Src`

and run the below command:

> configure -webengine-proprietary-codecs

After this configuration setting, I got this result:
[image]

I installed these Qt webengine compile prerequisites:

-Python 2.7.15

-Bison, Flex from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/files/win_flex_bison-2.5.5.zip/download)

-GPerf(32bit) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/gperf/3.0.1/gperf-3.0.1.exe/download?use_mirror=versaweb&download=)

-ActivePerl(64bit) from [here](https://www.activestate.com/products/activeperl/)

-LLVM(64bit) from [here](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html)

-Visual Studio 2017

-Windows 10 SDK

I also add them to Windows path and restart my machine.

Besides, I also install MSVC 2015 64-bit, MSVC 2017 32-bit, MSVC 2017 64-bit, Sources, Qt WebEngine, and Qt Network Authorization components.

Answer (score 0):

For windows I compiled qtwebengine with proprietary codecs using a bat file.

create qt5vars.bat. Paste below lines. Put this file in D:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\Src folder.

```
@echo off

REM Set up \Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, where <arch> is \c amd64, \c x86, etc.
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64_x86

REM Edit this location to point to the source code of Qt
SET _ROOT=D:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\Src

SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%

SET _ROOT=

REM Keeps the command line open when this script is run.
cmd /k
```

Run the bat file.

Note: for qtwebengine compilation you need to enable the long path name support otherwise compilation may fail. To enable it use below link:
https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing